# Connect points in order of x axis for df.plot.line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some values grouped by a column and compare them. I used

```
              for key, grp in df.groupby([gcol]):
                     ax = grp.plot.line(ax=ax,linestyle="--",marker="o",  x='steps', y='rouge_score', label=key, color=colors[gi])
                     gi += 1
                     if gi > len(colors) - 1: gi = 0
                     name += key + "_"
               ax.set_xticks(df["steps"].unique())
               ax.set_title(name)
```

However, as you see in the picture, it connects the points in order of y axis, while I want to connect them in order of x axis. For example for the red line it must first be connected to the point at 4500 and then the point at 9000

[image]

Comment: You need to sort your data according to the x values first. The data are simply plotted in the order they appear in your df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your values by `x`:

Setup a MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 2, 1], 'y': [0, 1, 2]})
```

Without sort:

```
df.plot.line(x='x', y='y', marker='o', ls='--')
```

[image]

With sort:

```
df.sort_values('x').plot.line(x='x', y='y', marker='o', ls='--')
```

[image]